# How to run Multiple iterative jobs in parallel in HADOOP

Tags: hadoop

I have a hadoop job which runs iteratively for a single file. Now if i have to run multiple jobs parallelly for each file in the directory whats the best practice to fallow in HADOOP.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to project [haloop](http://code.google.com/p/haloop/) which addresses iterative map reduce.
Then, if the files are large, then go ahead and use haloop, otherwise u may combine small files for better performance.